# How to add files to .nsf inside a lotus notes application using an external java program

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm working on a project where i need to get my output excel files stored into a lotus notes .nsf file so that all the people concerned could access it through a lotus notes application. There's already an existing application but the previous procedure is to add the excel files manually to the app. now they want it to be done automatically, using java (netbeans IDE).

So, my question is, can anyone direct me to a good resource on how to do this. typically without using the lotus domino designer or using only java API's.

Answer (score 4):

Start by reading Bob Balaban's book "Programming Domino with Java".  It's old, but it will give you an excellent start on understanding Domino concepts and the Java API.  It's *free*, because Bob has posted it as a series of PDFs in his blog, [here](http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush).  It actually probably covers everything you really need to know for a simple program that just creates documents and attaches files.  Of course, once you read it and start working on the code, you can come back here to StackOverflow for help with any specific questions.

Also -- all the documentation for the Java API is contained in the help database for Domino Designer.  Even though you don't want to, and don't need to use Domino Designer for your project, you should still install it so that you have easy access to the help for all the classes, methods and properties.

Oh, and one more thing.  There is one big thing missing from the book, which is the recycle() method for all the classes.  It hadn't been developed at the time the book was written, and it is critically important for avoiding memory leaks in code that processes lots of documents.  Here is an [article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097861) that explains it.

Comment: One more thing I'd like to add is that Bob Balaban also has some great blog posts about Garbage Collection which are more than worth a read: http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/archive?openview&title=garbage%20collection&type=cat&cat=garbage%20collection

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use Java to access the Notes API, you should be able to use the EmbedObject method of the NotesRichTextItem class.
It is all documented in the Designer help:

**embedObject method**

Given the name of a file or an application, either:

- Attaches the file you specify to a rich text item.
- Embeds an OLE/1 object in a rich text item. The OLE/1 object is created using the file you specify.

*Defined in: RichTextItem*

**Syntax:**

```
public EmbeddedObject embedObject(int type, String class,
String source, String name)
    throws NotesException
```

**Parameters**

```
int type
```

One of the following:

- EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT
- EmbeddedObject.EMBED_OBJECT (OLE/1 objects only)

  String class

Specify an empty string ("").

```
String source
```

Specify the name of the file to attach or embed.

```
String name
```

String. Name by which you can reference the EmbeddedObject later. Can be null.

**Return value**

```
EmbeddedObject
```

The newly attached file or embedded OLE/1 object.

**Usage**

Files can be attached on any supported platform. 
Files can be embedded as OLE/1 objects on any supported platform (if the file is of a supported type, such as a Lotus® application data file).